# Inheritance in the database or in Java classes?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate

I have the following problem. I have an assignment of employees, machines, and equipment to a work location. A work location has current and expired assignments. Assignments currently have the same properties. Later, however, the current and expired allocations of each type are certain. Now I'm not sure how and where to best solve this. I use Hibernate and a PostgreSQL database.

[image: Class Diagram]

Am I building an inheritance structure in the database? Or do I have duplicate fields in the database and simply build an inheritance for my Java classes that is not transferred to the database? Like e.g. like this

```
public class Assignment() {
        ...
}

public class EmployeeAssignment() extends Assignment {
    ... 
}

public class ExpiredEmployeeAssignment() extends Assignment {
        ...
}
```

Comment: Whatever you decide, changing the database schema down the line will be much harder than changing Java classes. Get the schema right!

Comment: How many attributes have your assigment entities? 2-3? 10-20?

Comment: @mentallurg 6-8

Comment: Do the Assignment entities refer other entities besides WorkLocation? For instance, does EmployeeAssignment refers Employee entity? Or EmployeeAssignment contains also employee attributes?

Comment: [Don't use table inheritance in PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_table_inheritance)

Comment: @mentallurg yeah ... I probably should have drawn a whole ERM.

Comment: This is clearly not inheritance, because the various subtypes of Assignment are not WorkLocations. I assume that somewhere you also have Employee, Machine, and Equipment? Then each Assignment assigns exactly one of those to a WorkLocation. You can do that with three Assignment tables, or with one that has three exclusive foreign keys (use CHECK to make them exclusive). I would leave expired entries in there but with a nullable ExpiredTimestamp, and exclude them from an ActiveAssignments view. Or use an "infinite future" date for current assignments, and index that as appropriate.

Comment: @cliffordheath: *This is clearly not inheritance* - this a strange statement. All Assignment classes are subclasses of the same `Assignment` class. Why is it *clearly* to you that it is *not* inheritance? I would say that *obviously it **is** inheritance* :)

Comment: @mentallurg The diagram shows no Assignment class. It looks like the OP is trying to make the Assignments subclasses of WorkLocation, which is nonsense of course.

Comment: Diagram - good point. But I believe that the diagram is wrong. Instead of 6 1:N relations there should be only 1 such relations, from WorkLocation to Assignment. Then 6 subclasses of Assignment.